# Is there a way to set the border to a non-zero value using GaussianBlur?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I know I can accomplish the same by first using copyMakeBorder which would enlarge the input image which then yields an oversized result from GaussianBlur from which I'd have to extract the original sized result.  However, for neatness sake really,  I'm just hoping there's some way of just telling GaussianBlur to use a given constant for padding internally so the proper result will be extracted internally.

Comment: you could write a myGaussianBlurWithPadding function that creates border and computes gaussian and returns original sized result...

Comment: gaussian blur has a border parameter: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur borderInterpolate : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#borderinterpolate

Comment: **borderInterpolate - "Computes the source location of an extrapolated pixel"**......I've seen those docs and the various places in the opencv docs that refer to it for pretty much any filter op, but I confess it doesn't make sense to me as to how that could be used in a call to a function like GaussianBlur because the last parameter in the arg list  of type int (int borderType).  so what is it that a person is supposed to do with function borderinterpolate in that context?

Comment: @user3288226 As far as I know, you're doing the best option to your case. There is no way to do this using only GaussianBlur, and borderInterpolate is already used internally when you call copyMakeBorder